# What's the cause of "Failed to preload gadget..." for Sharebox gadgets in IBM Connections

Tags: opensocial, ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I've followed the procedure documented at "[Adding new ways to share content](http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/connections/4.0/doc/en_us/ic4_p4.html#addingnewwaystosharecontent)"

...but keep getting an error:

```
Failed to preload gadget http://....

Detailed error: 400 Gadget is not trusted to render in this container. cre.iruntime:cre.iwidget.event:cre.wire:cre.iwidget:cre.iwidget.itemset:cre….ibm.connections.ee:ibm.connections.ee:container.nongadget:open-views.js:4
```

[sharebox error http://i7.minus.com/ibiLz4SSWA5EL8.png](http://i7.minus.com/ibiLz4SSWA5EL8.png)

This looks like some sort of trust problem with external servers, but my other gadgets (embedded experience & home page gadgets) on the same external host are all working fine.

What have I missed out in the configuration?

Comment: Did you select "trusted" as the security type when adding the gadget?

Comment: Yes, I selected trusted -- as it's required for share gadgets. Just wondered if there's an XML file somewhere that I need to edit to whitelist the fomain hosting the gadget. My opensocial-config.xml allows for all hosts.

Comment: It *shouldn't* be a domain problem since other gadgets are working, so it should be a "permission to use feature X" issue. I can take a closer look tomorrow but in the meantime you could try rendering with various permissions on the bootstrap page.

Comment: this is weird, I wasn't able to reproduce this on any of my test servers. I would recommend removing some features to see if that helps, or testing with different security levels on the bootstrap page. What version of connections are you running?

Comment: Could you post the gadget XML?

Comment: Guys, I'm out until Friday - I'll get back to you then. Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://jirathrowdown.appfusions.com/rest/gadgets/1.0/g/com.appfusions.jira.connections.immersive-for-connections:connections-gadgets/gadgets/jira-sharebox.xml

Comment: The gadget XML is available here:
http://jirathrowdown.appfusions.com/rest/gadgets/1.0/g/com.appfusions.jira.connections.immersive-for-connections:connections-gadgets/gadgets/jira-sharebox.xml

I've now got this working on the gadget bootstrap page if I select "Feature access" of "Everything (NOTE: not valid for production)". Anything less results in "Detailed error: 400 Gadget is not trusted to render in this container." in the browser console.

Note, my gadget is at http://dvdsmpsn.demos.ibm.com:2990/path/to/sharebox.xml and my connections server is at http://connectionsww.demos.ibm.com/

Comment: Btw: opensocial-config.xml is wide open with developer mode enabled and all servers whitelisted: http://pastebin.com/NMVaS3EH

Comment: Hmm, it looks like this may be a problem with the version of IBM Connections 4.0 - I'm upgrading to CR2 to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Scrub that, I'm already on CR3. Is there any problem with CR3?

Comment: not that I'm aware of.  I have found that folks use https when they mean http, and the two don't jive when adding them in the administration tab?  maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, shamefully, it looks like I missed out swapping the security attribute `whitelistEnabled="true"` to `whitelistEnabled="false"` in:

`/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01/config/cells/connectionswwCell01/LotusConnections-config/opensocial-config.xml`

Here:

`<security whitelistEnabled="false" featureAdminEnabled="true">`

More details in this slide: [How to add your own OpenSocial Gadgets to IBM Connections](http://www.slideshare.net/IBMSBT/sbt-webinar130911/15).

---

Of course, in a production system, you'll have to checkout the opensocial config using `wsadmin.sh`, edit, checkin & restart.